# How to Read tsv file without packages?

Tags: python

I want to read a TSV file in python and store each record as an element within a list.
I don't know how to achieve that without CSV, pandas, etc.

Comment: read file line by line and then split by `\t`

Comment: Is there a good reason you don't want to use, say, the `csv` module for this? `csv` supports the ability to specify what the separator character is, and it's part of the standard library, unlike `pandas`, so it should be included in any python installation.

Comment: This is a requirement in assessment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make a list of list from your tsv.

```
input = open("file.tsv","r")
rawText = input.read()
lines = rawText.split("\n")
listOfLists = k.split("\t") for k in lines
```

if you want to get the headers and make a dictionary you can modify the list of lists.

```
colNames = listOfLists[0][1:]
rowNames = listOfLists[k][0] for k in range(1,len(listOfLists))
aDictionary = {}
for n,k in enumerate(rowNames):
    aDictionary[k]={}
    for n2,k2 in enumerate(listOfLists[n+1][1:]):
        aDictionary[k][colNames[n2]]=listOfLists[n+1][n2+1]
```

**As your comment said "remove the header and keep everything in one list"**

```
oneBigList = []
```

now depending if you have headers on each row...

```
for k in listOfLists[1:]:
    oneBigList += k
```

or if you want to exclude the first element of each row

```
for k in listOfLists[1:]:
    oneBigList += k[1:]
```

Comment: thank you. is there any method to remove the header and keep each record as an element in a list, not a list of the list ?